# How do I copy all events from one calendar to another using the Google API and PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-calendar-api

as the title says, How do I copy all events from one calendar to another google using api and PHP?

I have a code to insert the event on my own calendar but, I'd like to insert like owner another users(email).

I have this and works fine:

```
 $createdEvent = $service->events->insert('my_own_email.7x@gmail.com', $event, array(
   'sendNotifications' => true
));
```

this works fine, but the idea is to make some like:

```
 $createdEvent = $service->events->insert('other_owner_email.7z@gmail.com', $event, array(
   'sendNotifications' => true
));
```

graphically would go to the event calendar and make click on the "more actions" and make owner to other ... How make the same but using the google API?

Comment: If the code works fine for you, it will work fine using another email address. The other user just has to grant your application permission to access their account first.

Comment: yeah! but if I grant the app with my own credentials, and in code level, I want to put as the owner to other user and not me? how can I do that?

Comment: So you want to sign in as you, then you want to be able to modify my account as though you are me, but without me granting you access first?

Comment: ah yeah, some like that but to do in level code, is possible using the Google's calendar API and PHP?